# How can I get data from a PHPMyAdmin database into java code?

Tags: java, phpmyadmin, mamp

I was talking to a friend and they gave me code for it, but it only works for mySQL, is there a way I can get it to work for phpMyAdmin/MAMP?

```
class Main 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    loadData tb = new loadData();
    ArrayList<user> userData = tb.loadData();
    Iterator<user> tempIT = userData.iterator();
    while(tempIT.hasNext()==true)
    {
      user temp = tempIT.next();
      System.out.println(temp.getUN());
      System.out.println(temp.getPW());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHPMyAdmin is a software tool intented to manage MySQL Databases over the web, it is not a DataBase, so you can't "access it" to retreive data.
Definition from the [Official Website](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) :

"phpMyAdmin is a free software tool written in PHP, intended to handle the administration of MySQL over the Web. phpMyAdmin supports a wide range of operations on MySQL and MariaDB."